How do you build logic from a new if...then... statement?
All logic originates from the law of cause and effect, which then originates from the if X then Y connective.
However, because of the paradox of the material implication, the Truth table for the if X then Y connective equates to nonsense for the dual cases (F, T) and (F, F).
Who, then, has proposed base e logic, built from the modified if X then Y connective, which yields the following?

if T then T = T
if T then F = F
if F then T = vacuous truth (because everything proceeds from a contradiction)
if F then F = not even wrong, because it is nonsense to infer a causal relationship between two nonexistent entities.

Rings logical.

The premise of your question, that all logic originates from the law of cause and effect, is false. Logic is prior to cause and effect, and it's not even clear that cause and effect can be modeled by implication or any other logical operation.

@DavidGudeman I beg to differ ("that all logic originates from the law of cause and effect... false"), because we cannot conceive of a world where cause and effect does not hold but logic reigns.

@CosmicCat I'd argue we quite regularly conceive of such worlds.  As a case study, a common question in physics is whether acceleration causes force or force causes acceleration.  The most accepted answer is neither: they merely go together.  I do agree that we have a strong tendency to collect statements of such systems into if/then patterns, and I'm not sure if we ever collect them in other ways, but I do think its common for individual statements to not exhibit causality.

@CortAmmon I beg to differ with regards to your proposed counterexample also. Force, by definition, is that which causes acceleration. By definition, acceleration can never cause force.

@CosmicCat You may make such a statement, but it is not the current prevailing opinion of scientists.  Choosing wikipedia as a source (because it's easy), "At any instant of time, the net force on a body is equal to the body's acceleration multiplied by its mass or, equivalently, the rate at which the body's momentum is changing with time."  Equivalence is well recognized as not a causal relationship.

There's some fudging to be made, given that Newton phrased his laws in Latin using language a few centuries old, but most readings I have found treat that as an equality/equivalence relationship, not a cause/effect relationship.  And Wikipedia's later translation (intended to be more of a translation of the Latin), use "proportional."

You are arguing from personal lack of imagination, which is not a persuasive argument form. There are lots of us who can conceive of a world without cause and effect but with logic. In fact, I hold that there is, in fact, such a world, the world of mathematical objects. But even if we could not conceive of such a world, your conclusion would not follow. It is a non sequitur.

@DavidGudeman I beg to differ with regards to your counterexample ("the world of mathematical objects"). For instance, if we have a system of linear equations, and we change one of the coefficients, that results in to a different solution set. The only difference is that while physicists prefer to say "the change in the coefficients in the system caused the solutions to change" mathematicians use "to give rise to". Preference of verb, really.

@DavidGudeman Also like Bumble brought up, some philosophers think that cause and effect applies to Universals. Therefore not all philosophers share your perspective regarding the absence of causality in the mathematical universe.

Changing an equation is part of the physical world or the mental world, not the mathematical world. Mathematically, there are just two different equations one considered subsequently to the other. At to universals, I don't think you understand what that means.

See Examples of non-truth functionals connectives

What are cases 3 and 4? "vacuous truth" is True and "not even wrong" is???


Logic does not originate with cause and effect. Logic, at least in its simple classical form, is concerned with the relation of logical consequence between the truths of propositions. Causes and effects are relations between things, or possibly between universals. Logical relations are quite different from causal ones. Causal relations are directional, because causes precede their effects; implicational relations are often bidirectional. Causal relations usually involve physical proximity and mechanism; those are not relevant in logic.

The paradoxes of material implication are not nonsense. However, they do often indicate that the conditional in question is not the material conditional. The case where the conditional is true because its antecedent and consequent are both false is necessary for the form of modus tollens to be valid. If A then B; B is false; therefore, A is false. For this to work, the conditional "if A then B" must be capable of being true when A and B are both false, otherwise there could be no sound instances of this form. Logic is not about inferring causal relationships; it is concerned with inferring the truth or falsity of one proposition from others.

There have been proposed 'gappy' conditionals, in which the conditional fails to have a truth value when its antecedent is false, but they have not proved useful.

In answer to the question in the title, if you wish to build a logic around a new conditional you have two main options. You can devise a non-classical logic with a different conditional. This is the approach taken by relevance logics and connexive logics, both of which are primarily motivated by a desire for a conditional that is not a truth function. The second option is to retain classical logic as the underlying logic and define a conditional that is stronger, in the sense of more restrictive, than the material conditional. This is the approach taken by modal logics and conditional logics. Conditionals in this category include strict conditionals and variably strict conditionals.



"Gappy conditionals" <- The word you look for spells "partial function". An if... then... connective that fails for (F, T) and (F, F), a mathematician would name "partial function". And like partial differential equations, partial functions exceed total functions (such as the connective that gives rise to the paradoxes of the material implication) in inscrutability. But they subside in greater generality.

I agree that 'gappy' is closely related to the concept of a partial function. But the terms 'gappy' and 'glutty' are commonly used in logic, both to describe connectives themselves and logical relations more generally, so I chose the word advisedly. There are plenty of alternatives to the material conditional that are not gappy: conditionals do not have to be truth functions.

All of logic did not originate from if X then Y.  Aristotilian logic, for instance, used different structures.
I see your point when we explore logic (such as first order logic) as is taught in a modern sense, but would argue that it isn't so much if X then Y that is at the core as a binary operation "f(X,Y)" that we happen to associate with the English phrase if X then Y.
I'd argue the person you are looking for is George Boole.  He is the one that found a meaningful way to model logic with mathematics that permits the sort of mathematical statements you made.  And its in his general era that the particular operation you mention became the preferred concept (phrased as if X then Y), over the other potential meanings of "if" which had different truth tables.

@DavidGudeman I beg to differ ("All of logic did not originate from if X then Y."), because we cannot conceive of a world where cause and effect does not hold but logic reigns.

"All of logic did not originate from if X then Y. Aristotilian logic, for instance, used different structures." According to Jan Lukasiewicz, Aristotle's syllogisms were not as portrayed in the literature, but conditionals. See Aristotle's Syllogistic from the standpoint of modern formal logic.
